# How can I make my polygon rotate without using the rotate function in the library

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, rotation, polygon

I have this graph that shows a polygon that is supposed to do what it is already doing but in addition to rotate the polygon all the time. I got this to work using the rotate transform ("r = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate(theta)") but I am supposed to do this without any existing functions. 
Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

xlist = [1, -1, -1]
ylist = [4, 5, 3]

xlist.append(xlist[0])
ylist.append(ylist[0])

plt.plot(xlist, ylist)

for i in range(len(xlist)-1):
    print("Point",i,"= (",xlist[i],",",ylist[i],")")

i = 0
velocity_Y = 1
while (i < 16):
    xlist = [ item+1 for item in xlist]
    ylist = [ item+velocity_Y for item in ylist]

    plt.plot(xlist, ylist)
    velocity_Y = velocity_Y - 0.17
    i = i+1

plt.axis([-2, 25, -2, 10])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is this for a school assignment (your question suggests it is)? if so, please take a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Yes. I just hope someone will show me in the right direction.

Comment: you have to calculate all from scratch - get vector between point in polygon and rotation point (substract both points), calculate angle, rotate this vector, add new vector to rotation point to get new position for point in polygon. Repeate it for all points.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions